# Difference Byte Array and File Java

Tags: java, android, hash, arrays

I'm reading tags from RFID Chips and i want to send them to a server. When I'm hashing the byte Array before converting into a file and uploading via ftp i get a different hash value than the hash of the uploaded file.
This is what i am using for hashing the byte array:

```
public static byte[] SHAsum(byte[] convertme)
                throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
            return md.digest(convertme);
        }

        private static String byteArray2Hex(final byte[] hash) {
            Formatter formatter = new Formatter();
            for (byte b : hash) {
                formatter.format("%02x", b);
            }
            return formatter.toString();
        }
```

and this is how i upload the file:

```
private byte[] EfSodBin;

    try {
                con.connect(IP, 21);
                con.login(FTP_USER, FTP_PW);

                InputStream isDG2 = new ByteArrayInputStream(DG2);
                InputStream isSOD = new ByteArrayInputStream(EfSodBin);

                con.makeDirectory(DocNu);
                con.storeFile(DocNu + "/DG2.bin", isDG2);
                con.storeFile(DocNu + "/SOD.bin", isSOD);

                Log.d("FTP", "files uploaded");

                con.logout();

            } catch (SocketException e2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e2.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
```

The solution was to add following after con.login:

```
con.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
```

Comment: it would help to have an example of content, with the 2 hashes.

Comment: I analysed the content. Sometimes Bytes are added and then the file goes on as it should.

Answer (score 0):

While reading the file from FTP, if the file had been correctly read using the UTF-8 encoding, then it may have used Byte Order Mark (BOM), Some vendors use this to notify start of actual data and some dont, I am not sure why you using  SHA-256.But i think it may also have the issue if you dont use correct encoding type.

After reading the file from ftp, you can review to see this extra charecter , if you see then you may need to handl that.

Unfortunately you have to handle this in code, after you get this string from ftp , remove this.

```
private String removeUTF8BOM(String s) {
    if (s.startsWith( "\uFEFF"))
{
        s = s.substring(1);
    }
    return s;
}
```